# Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract class override

Tags: magento, overriding

As title suggest i want to override `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` class , I know that it is `abstract class`. and we can easily override abstract class using local directory like `app\code\local\Mage\Payment\Model\Method\Abstract.php`. But i want to know is there any other option for me ? Because this option is not safe with different magento version.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: keyur is not impossible....you can do this by replicate abstract class of that abstract lcass

Comment: An abstract class is never instantiated, it can never be rewritten. If you override, you need to take care of future upgrades

Comment: @AmitBera ya i know that i can achieve this using replicating method in local folder. But i want to just to know is there any other option available for me ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy suppose if i override this method method using local folder means auto loader class. is create any issue in other magento version ?

Comment: You can use traditional class override and copy. This will let you modify a single Abstract class, but you'll need to merge any changes from upgraded versions into this class — and you may cause system problems when you forget to do that.

Comment: Also somewhere on the blog I read this (not in favor though) For ex: Copy Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract from app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier to app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier, do NOT change the class name, just change or add the methods as you need. This is a trick. Magento loads a class from several locations, and app/code/local comes before app/code/core

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy thanks for the valuable info....nd plz post as answer so i can accept ur answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'**Override**' is a method where you copy a class from the Magento core into the local code. For ex:

```
app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
```

An override is where you tell Magento to "`Use this class file instead of the other class file`". Similar, but different from a rewrite. `Rewrites` are considered better practice because they're less likely to cause problems with upgrades and extension compatibility.

```
An abstract class is never instantiated, it can never be rewritten.
```

If you override, you need to take care of future upgrades. You can't rewrite an abstract class. The rewrite system works because Magento uses a factory pattern to instantiate model, blocks, and helpers.

The other alternative is to use a traditional class override. For ex: Copy

```
app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
```

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php
```

Also somewhere on the blog I read this (**not in favor though**) For ex: Copy

```
Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract
```

from

`app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier`

to

```
app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier
```

Do NOT change the class name, just change or add the methods as you need.

This is a trick. Magento loads a class from several locations, and **app/code/local** comes before **app/code/core**

Good luck!!!

Comment: Thanks for valuable info +1 for you